# Processing create DXF from inside Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, processing, dxf

this works in processing and it's IDE of version 2.2. Moved that to Eclipse and the drawing part works

```
import processing.core.*;
import processing.dxf.*;

public class ShowCameraParts extends PApplet {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    boolean record = false;
    QuadWith2EarsAttached[] tp = new QuadWith2EarsAttached[1];

    public void setup() {
        size(Settings.WINDOW_X, Settings.WINDOW_Y);
        // lights(); lights() is not available with this renderer.
        background(200);
        noFill();
        stroke(0);
        tp[0] = new QuadWith2EarsAttached(this);
    }

    public void draw() {

        if (record == true) {
            beginRaw(DXF,"CameraPart.dxf"); // Start recording to the file
        }

        tp[0].draw();

        if (record == true) {
            endRaw();
            record = false; // Stop recording to the file
        }
    }

    public void keyPressed() {
        if (key == 'R' || key == 'r') { // Press R to save the file
            record = true;
            println("DXF Done");
        }
    }
}
```

but when I run it in Eclipse I get this error when "r" is pressed

```
DXF Done
beginRaw() is not available with this renderer.
endRaw() is not available with this renderer.
```

What is the right way to create an dxf from the graphic created in processing ?

Comment: Can you try ```size(Settings.WINDOW_X, Settings.WINDOW_Y,P3D);``` ? Also can you list the contents of the ```QuadWith2EarsAttached``` so people can run your code ?

Comment: actually I thought the same but than I get this error "libEGL warning: failed to create a pipe screen for i965". The code is actually just a view line drawings as a test you could replace the draw command and would get the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

strangely since I have uncommented

```
import processing.dxf.*;
```

it simply works. Not sure why but it does the job